# How to use vue getters to find a value inside an object?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to get a specific value of an object inside the state of vuex.

Let me show you what I mean:

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";

export default createStore({
    state: {
        cards: [{
                title: "Blog 1",
                htmlCode: "This is blog 1",
                index: 1,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 2",
                htmlCode: "This is blog 2",
                index: 2,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 3",
                htmlCode: "This is blog 3",
                index: 3,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 4",
                htmlCode: "This is blog 4",
                index: 4,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 5",
                htmlCode: "This is blog 5",
                index: 5,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 6",
                htmlCode: "This is blog 6",
                index: 6,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 7",
                htmlCode: "This is blog 7",
                index: 7,
            },
        ],
    },
    getters: {
      getTodoById: (state) => (id) => {
        return state.cards.find(todo => todo.index === id)
      }
    },
    mutations: {},
    actions: {},
    modules: {},
});
```

Now if I insert this value in my code: `<p>{{ this.$store.getters.getTodoById(2) }}</p>`, I get this as result: `{ "title": "Blog 2", "htmlCode": "This is blog 2", "index": 2 }`
What I want, is the value of for example`htmlCode` and that result would be `This is blog 2`.

Hopefully someone understands what I mean.

For clarity: **I want this result in the browser: This is blog 2**

It is very important for my website that it is done with vuex getters.

Comment: have you tried to access the title via dot notation? `{{ $store.getters.getTodoById(2).title }}` ? I would probably work around to haven't these unreadable code in the template are and create a method or computed property instead that returns only the title.

Answer (score 1):

This is a posible solution

```js
getTodoById: (state) => (id) => {
  const todo = state.cards.find(todo => todo.index === id)
  return todo.htmlCode
}
```

Other solution is create a `todo` data in the componente and in the `created()` add your getter and asign to this data.

```js
  data() {
    return {
      todo: null,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.todo = this.$store.getters.getTodoById(id) // for example extracted by the route
  },
```

```html
<p>{{ todo.htmlCode }}</p>
```

Comment: `find` may return `null`. Maybe return `todo?.htmlCode ?? ''` or something instead.

Comment: Yeh or a `v-cloak` in the template or a `v-if="todo"`

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
<p>{{ this.$store.getters.getTodoById(2).htmlCode}}</p>
```

Comment: They want to output `htmlCode`, not `index`